# Why does the variable always outputs 1, even though it's incremented in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I tried solving a Problem I found online. I successfully solved the problem, but there's one small error that I couldn't solve.

**The Problem**

> Write a guessing game where the user has to guess a secret number.
>   After every guess the program tells the user whether their number was
>   too large or too small. At the end the number of tries needed should
>   be printed.

Here's my code:

```
// Generate a random number between 1 and 100
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100)) + 1;
var running = true;    

while(running) {
    var tries = 1;
    var input = prompt("Take a guess");

    if (input == num) {
        console.log("Correct!");

        console.log("Number of tries: " + tries);
        running = false;
    }else if (input > num) {
        console.log("Too big");
    }else if (input < num) {
        console.log("Too small");
    }
    tries++;
}
```

> **Bug**
>
> > Even if the user takes more than 1 try, the program still says,
> >
> > > *Number of tries: 1*

Please explain what am I doing wrong.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reinitialize `tires` on each iteration of your while loop:

```
while(running) {
    var tries = 1;
    ...
}
```

Try initializing outside of your loop.

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100)) + 1;
var running = true;    
var tries = 1;

while(running) {
    var input = prompt("Take a guess");

    if (input == num) {
        console.log("Correct!");

        console.log("Number of tries: " + tries);
        running = false;
    }else if (input > num) {
        console.log("Too big");
    }else if (input < num) {
        console.log("Too small");
    }
    tries++;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `tries` decalres inside the `while` body. So, any loop iteration, this variable gets the value 1. To solve this issue, you should declare & initialize the variable outside to the loop:

```
// Generate a random number between 1 and 100
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
var running = true;
var tries = 1;

while (running) {
  var input = prompt("Take a guess");

  if (input == num) {
    console.log("Correct!");
    console.log("Number of tries: " + tries);
    running = false;
  } else if (input > num) {
    console.log("Too big");
  } else if (input < num) {
    console.log("Too small");
  }

  tries++;
}
```

**Note:** Do not use `console.log()`, use `alert()` instead. The console is for debugging, not for notify user messages.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your problem. If you put a variable inside while function it will be reset each time meaning that it will be 1 each time.

If you put it outside it run just fine. Also, I believe that promt returns a string not a number that is why I would recommend you either to convert a number to string or a promt to number.

Here is the working code:

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100)) + 1;
var running = true;    
var tries = 1;

while(running) {

    var input = parseFloat(prompt("Take a guess"));

    if (input == num) {
        console.log("Correct!");

        console.log("Number of tries: " + tries);
        running = false;
    }else if (input > num) {
        console.log("Too big");
    }else if (input < num) {
        console.log("Too small");
    }
    tries++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, it works without the conversion. Is it a bad practice to not to do it?

Comment: It is not, but sometimes with some browsers it causes an error as it presents a number as a string. If you do not do it then it is fine, but before releasing I would check different browsers and different versions of these brosers

Comment: Ok, and I guess I wouldn't be able to use the '===' operator as 'input === num' either.

Comment: Sorry have not noticed the operator. If you use '==' then there will be no issue